# Asynchronously setting Image.Source with NotifyPropertyChange

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, inotifypropertychanged

I have an Image that is modified via some sliders, whose values are sent to a method that procedurally (re)generates a BitmapSource.

Currently things are cumbersome, since the sliders' movements are lagging. I believe this is due to the blocking nature of the `Update` method.

I tried to "make things more async", but apparently had no success, since slider movement is still laggy.

I post my code below, and the question is: what am I doing wrong, and what is the right way to update a procedurally generated Image asynchronously in WPF?

One thing to note is that IDE complains that `Update()` calls are not awaited, "execution continues before the call is completed", but I'm not sure what this means, or what I should do about it.

---

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Miotec.FranjasSenoidais.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Miotec.FranjasSenoidais"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="Imagem" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Image x:Name="franjas" Width="800" Height="600"
                   Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="SliderLateral" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <toolkit:RangeSlider Orientation="Vertical"
                                 Maximum="1" Minimum="0" Step="0.01"
                                 HigherValue="{Binding Maximo}" 
                                 LowerValue="{Binding Minimo}"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="SliderEspessuraFranja" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Slider Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding Espessura}"
                    Minimum="4" Maximum="16"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs (DataContext in code behind for brevity)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Miotec.FranjasSenoidais
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public double Maximo
        {
            get { return _maximo; }
            set
            {
                _maximo = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Maximo");
                Update();
            }
        }

        double _maximo = 1;

        public double Minimo
        {
            get { return _minimo; }
            set
            {
                _minimo = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Minimo");
                Update();
            }
        }
        double _minimo = 0;

        public int Espessura
        {
            get { return _espessura; }
            set
            {
                _espessura = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Espessura");
                Update();
            }
        }
        int _espessura = 10;


        public BitmapSource ImageSource { get { return _imageSource; } }
        BitmapSource _imageSource;


        private async Task Update()
        {
            await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                // somewhat lengthy operation
                _imageSource = FranjasSenoidais.Criar((int)franjas.Width,
                                       (int)franjas.Height,
                                       Maximo, Minimo,
                                       Espessura);

            }));

            RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;
        }




        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

FranjasSenoidais.cs

```
public static class FranjasSenoidais
{
    public static BitmapSource Criar(int largura,
                                     int altura,
                                     double maximo,
                                     double minimo,
                                     int espessura)
    {
        if (largura < 2 || altura < 2)
            return null;

        var targetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(largura, altura,
                                                96, 96,
                                                PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        var visual = new DrawingVisual();

        using (var dc = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            double xcenter = largura * 0.5;
            double ycenter = altura * 0.5;

            dc.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Black, null, new Point(xcenter, ycenter), espessura, espessura);
        }

        targetBitmap.Render(visual);
        targetBitmap.Freeze();

        return targetBitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: to me MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged is wrong already. Window should not be INotifyPropertyChanged, only the viewmodel should

Comment: @Steve I know, that's why I wrote "for brevity" observation. Besides, the question does not concern MVVM, and if you are not tied to MVVM, anything can implement INPC, IMO.

Comment: Using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke doesn't help because the current dispatcher is the UI thread dispatcher. Try replacing Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with Task.Run. This will schedule the image load on the thread pool. Also, I think you can use void as the return type of your Update method because you don't need to "await" it in your setters.

Comment: @CoolBlue when I do what you suggest, I get an `InvalidOperationException` because the object cannot be accessed by a different thread (which is due to `Task.Run()` I presume).

Comment: I think if you do what I suggested but add MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource")) then it will be ok.

Comment: @CoolBlue actually things started to work fine just by moving the RaisePropertyChanged call _into_ the `BeginInvoke` call. And actually BeginInvoke seems to be necessary, because otherwise I get the exception.

Comment: So it's not laggy anymore?

Comment: Exactely. Apparently the notification itself was lengthy, or its placement after the await made the UI response seem laggy, but this single line change allowed me to make `Update()` not async and things behave without lag.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a couple changes. @Cool-Blue comment is right. Just move the dispatching into your INotify implementation and queue up your cpu bound process on a task. Be sure to fire property changed from that thread, see below:

```
    private void Update() {
        Task.Run(new Action(() => {
            // somewhat lengthy operation
            _imageSource = FranjasSenoidais.Criar((int)franjas.Width,
                                   (int)franjas.Height,
                                   Maximo, Minimo,
                                   Espessura);
            RaisePropertyChanged("ImageSource");
        }));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string name) {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
```

Comment: Still getting `InvalidOperation` since `franjas` is in another thread and its properties are accessed inside the `Task.Run()` call.

Comment: Actually it's `_imageSource` that is being set.